# change caret color of input text field

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I'm creating a signup page in my android app using flash cc. The caret inside input textfield seems dimmer which makes it difficult for user to know which textfield is currently active. I can create a box below textfield and change its color when active but what I wanna know is if I can customize caret in any way? I've looked into internet but couldn't find anything. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Never seen anything like that, and I'm familiar with Flash for quite a while. You can (probably) emulate it for single-line text with **TextField. caretIndex**, **TextField.scrollH**, and **TextField. 
getCharBoundaries(...)**, but I think the simpler and better way would be to highlight the whole input text around its border in a noticeable manner.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have seen it done in android studio. But i don't think it can be done in flash as3. I guess I have to use the highlight method.